# JavaScript + jQuery this scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, scope

I've this problem - I really can't solve it by my self. I've downloaded [this jQuery plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/).

I have *x* number of divs that are jQuery objects are being extended by the following:

```
    $('.colorSelector').ColorPicker({
        color: '#0000ff',
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('.colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        }
    });
```

What I want is to retrieve the `$('.colorSelector')` 'this' reference (inside the ColorPicker method's object) and replace the onChange method that the 'css' method can be assigned to `$(this)` selector instead of `$(.colorSelector div')`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Do you want to use relative selectors instead of absolute ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I've resolved the problem in another way. Either way thanx for the replies.

**EDIT:**
Well, I used a really 'primitive' solution and assiged unique id's. Than I was able to retrieve instances by those ids - but iny my opinion the solution is not really what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, but I think you want to get the children `div` using `$(this)`:

```
$(this).find('div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
```

If it is not that, please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I've ment.